# Node + websocket send message to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have a nodejs websocket server and need to send data from my serial port to the client every time it send data to me.

This is my ws on connection

```
wss.on('connection', ws => {
    ws.on('message', message => {
      console.log(`Received message => ${message}`)
    })
    ws.send('ho!')
})
```

This is my serial on Data

```
parser.on('data', (dados) => {
    console.log(dados.toString('utf8'));
})
```

Basically, when the serial send me some data, i need to send it to the client.

Is there any way of making that trick? i thought that i could have some global variable and make it as a bridge between both actions.

i.e: Whenever serial send me some data i put it on my variable and each 2 seconds my ws server sends whatever is in that variable to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your 'data' callback, instead of the line of `console.log(dados.toString('utf8'));`

you can put the below code:

```
wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
  if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
    client.send(dados.toString('utf8'));
  }
});
```

the collection `wss.clients` should contain only one ws client as i understand, based on your architecture.

Comment: Thats it. Thank you. Why wss.client should contain only one client?

Comment: As you described, you have only one client connect to the websocket. If 2 clients will connected, you will have 2 in the list, etc.